# simple PHP integer conversion

Tags: php

convert this: $300
to this : 300

- can't do it with intval() or (int)
  typecasting
- if the non-numerical character is
  suffixed (300$), both works and
  returns 300
- if it is prefixed it returns 0
- the non-numerical character can be anything other than the "$"(i.e. "askldjflksdjflsd")

Please help

**EDIT** : list items are not requirements, they are a list of activities and observations I have made. Sorry:(

Comment: Does that not-a-requirement deal include the final bullet?

Comment: I see.  So the bullets are actually observations about trying to do it with `intval()` and `(int)` rather than requirements?  Sorry, but you've gotta be clearer when you ask questions.  -1

Comment: no prob. was my fault anyway:(

Comment: You might want to edit the question to make it clearer whether the final part was intended to be an observation too because it sure reads like a requirement but the rest of the list isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$number = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: I get "Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in php shell code on line 1" in PHP 5.2.10

Comment: Yeah, parameter 1 should be a constant.  Parameter 2 should be the variable.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Went ahead and made the `filter_var` change, since that clearly seems to be the intent.

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $num, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Do remember to make sure that you actually get a match at all, though. You could also try wrapping the expression in a group so you get all groups of digits contained in the string, which may be useful (especially if you need tighter matching, e.g. the number must be prefixed by a specific substring. Also you may need to replace the regex with `"/\d+(\.\d+)?/"` if you need to account for decimals, too (or `"/(\d+|\d*\.\d+)/"` if you want decimals with a notation like `".50"` (=0.5) too.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of all the non-digits in the input by doing:

```
$input = preg_replace('/\D/','',$input);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print (int) trim('$300', '$');
```

No need for a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = (integer) str_replace('$', '', $number);
```

Comment: Does not match all of the OP's requirements.

Comment: Yeh it does. He said no use of `(int)`. I used `(integer)`

Comment: "the non-numerical character can be anything other than the "$"(i.e. "askldjflksdjflsd")", for example. I think when he said not to use `(int)`, it was because using `(int)` alone doesn't get the job done.

Comment: Violates two of the bullets in the question: "can't do it with intval() or (int) typecasting" (though that may have been an observation that those don't work on the target strings, not a requirement); "the non-numerical character can be anything other than the '$' (i.e. 'askldjflksdjflsd')"

Comment: Would revoke downvote, given clarification that apparently the bullets were observations rather than clarifications; however, vote too old to be allowed to change.

Comment: @matchu Agreed.  However, there's an exception for edited questions.  Maybe would allow Coronatus to recoup some rep with a little bit of coordination?

Comment: @Dathan: made a nominal formatting edit to allow vote changes.